# Meaning of $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I have seen cases where it refers to infinity, for example, the infinite de morgan's rule that obsoletes mathematical induction.

I have also seen cases where it refers to each member of natural number such as infinite intersection of sets with finite elements.

So my question is, if I see $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}$, under what circumstances should I interpret it as

1. $P(\infty)$; or
2. $\forall n\in N$

I have not studied much set theory and I just want to know the bare minimum to thrive in real analysis. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{A_i\}_{i\in\mathcal I}$ a collection of sets in $X$ where $\mathcal I$ is an indice set (not necessarily countable). Then, $$\bigcap_{i\in \mathcal I}A_i=\{x\in X\mid \forall i\in \mathcal I, x\in A_i\},$$
and
$$\bigcup_{i\in\mathcal I}A_i=\{x\in X\mid \exists i\in \mathcal I:x\in A_i\}.$$

For example, $$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)=\{0\},$$
and $$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\left[-1+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}\right]=(-1,1).$$

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But the book and examples I am exposed to do not give much specification. In particular, it uses $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}$ and $\cap_{n\in N}$. interchangeably and yet ironically, point out the difference between them in some cases. So my question is, is there any general consensus as to set notation with only infinity sign.

Comment: I guess you rather mean $\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb N}$ than $\bigcap_{i\in N}$. And yes it's the same thing... @AndesLam

Comment: OK, let me put it in this way, If you were given $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}$, what will be your first guess? does it mean intersection for all natural number? Or does it mean infinity?

Comment: there is no guess, $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty $ has no sense... what has sense is $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ where $A_i$ are sets. Moreover, $\bigcup_{i}$ is a union, not an intersection.@AndesLam

Comment: and as I told you before, yes $\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb N}$ and $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty $ is the same thing. @AndesLam

Comment: @projectilemotion: thanks a lot. I edited.